# How to remove required field in checkout

Tags: validation, magento2, option-type, checkout, magento2.4

How to change the required field to an optional field on the checkout page that can be enabled and disabled from the backend like a middle name?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in the checkout_index_index.xml to remove the required entry at the respective item name. For example, I have removed the required for first name.

```
<item name="firstname" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Comment: can we control true or false from backend in this?